# Can the By strategy tagName be replaced with cssSelector for the same value?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver, tagname

I replaced the locator tagName with cssselector without changing the arguments and the code still worked perfectly.
The previous script was:

```
Driver.findElement(By.tagName("*enter tagName*");
```

Replacement code is:

```
Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*enter tagName*");
```

The code worked despite the fact that I did not use any cssSelector combination.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This worked correctly since tag name alone is a correct CSS Selector.
Generally CSS Selector is may look like the following: `tagName[attributeName='attributeValue']` where you can omit the attribute name and value and locate the element based on `tagName` only. So `tagName` lonely will still be a correct CSS Selector.

Answer (score 0):

*`By.TAG_NAME`* is always equivalent to *`By.CSS_SELECTOR`*

---

As per the definition of [find_element()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.html#WebDriver.find_element):

```
elif by == By.TAG_NAME:
    by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
```

Hence the previous line of code:

```
Driver.findElement(By.tagName("enter tagName");
```

and the replacement line of code:

```
Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("enter tagName");
```

was equivalent.